# Optimize performance of huge content HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page, reading a text file and showing it on the site on runtime. I use jQuery to parse the file and append to the page with the following code:

```js
resultArray.forEach(function (val) {
   $('#OutputArea').append(appendText(val.content));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <ol id="OutputArea">
        <li class="someClass"> some content...</li>
        <li class="someClass"> some content...</li>
        <li class="someClass"> some content...</li>
        <li class="someClass"> some content...</li>
        <li class="someClass"> some content...</li>
        <!-- New content will add below -->
    </ol>
</div>
```

It was okay when there are only thousands of line, however as more content appended to the page, the site will become less responsive, i.e. Took long time to render and laggy when scroll.

[image]

I understand the browser will become slower as the page do take a lot of resources, however is there a way to optimize the performance of it? Thanks.

### **26/7/2018 Update**

I've done a couple things to speed up the process:

1.Make use of DocumentFragment instead of appending html strings like `<li class="someClass"> some content...</li>`

2.Instead of jQuery forEach loop, the following loop did make things sightly faster

```js
  var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  for(var i =0 ;i<resultArray.length;i++)
  {
      var val = resultArray[i];
       fragment.appendChild(appendText(val.content, val.id));
  }            
  document.getElementById("LogArea").appendChild(fragment);
```

3. Adding `will-change:transform;` CSS property to the div, the scrolling is MUCH more faster than before.

I also found that removing the `counter-increment` will make the render a lot faster, almost 70%. I use the following CSS to create my own `<li>` number style.
My guessing is that the `li:before` `content` calculation did a lot of work load to the rendering? I had no idea on how to get over it.

```css
ol { 
    counter-reset: item;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 10px
}

li {
  display: -webkit-box;
}

li:before { 
    content: counter(item) "  "; 
    counter-increment: item ;
    color: gray;
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    font-size:14px;
}
li:last-child:before {
    content: "";
}
```

Comment: Is it an option to lazy load your content? Like facebook, only parse the html if the user scrolls to it. You don't need to load html that is not shown (yet).

Comment: If you are going to load a bunch of stuff, it will be slow regardless. Lazy load the content to speed up performance significantly.

Comment: @Huangism Thanks, but will those css counter stuff benefit from lazy loading? Seems its the root cause of slow rendering, still looking at it..

Comment: Sorry, I haven't had the need to use those for large files so I wouldn't be able to answer that

Comment: @Huangism Actually i'm trying to build a log viewer where sort and aggregate logs from different file, the performance was acceptable. When I try to add the line number like visual studio by the CSS style above, i found it become extremely slow to render when including `counter-increment`.

Comment: If the css is the issue, then can you add line numbers in the markup instead?

Comment: Now i create the line number with my own jQuery scripting, and the performance is MUCH more better than pure CSS, it's like 40s with 6s, I may use the jQuery way than, however apart from performance consideration, i'd rather take the pure CSS way to do it, as its much more maintainable and clean.

Answer (score 0):

A few thoughts

1. Only append once. So build a var of all your list items

```js
var text = '';
resultArray.forEach(function (val) {
   text += appendText(val.content);
});
$('#OutputArea').append(text);
```

2. Chunk your text file. So the most important file is loaded / parsed first.
3. Build an API with pagination